# How to extract desired Json List object along with remaining Json properties to a model class?

Tags: c#, json, api, deserialization

//Here is the Json I am currently working with..

```
{
    "groups": null,
    "data": [{
            "type": 123,
            "name": "Name123"
        },
        {
            "type": 567,
            "name": "SecondName"

        }
    ],
    "total": 2

}
```

//here is the model class where I want to deserialize the last object  "data" including "group" and also total

```
public class JsonModel
{
   public class Data
  {
   public int type { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
  }
 
   public object groups { get; set; }
   public Date[] data { get; set; }
   public int total { get; set; }
}
                   //FYI using RestSharp to perform the request 
                 response = HttpGet("Url")
                   parsedResponse =   JToken.Parse(response.content);
        JsonModel.Date expectedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModel.Date> 
          (parsedResponse["data"].Last.ToString());


//After deserialzing I only get the type and name.. how to also get the groups and total here in my JsonModel to correctly map it.. I understand I am deserializing to JsonModel.Date thats why.. but how can I include the total and groups property..
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the online tool to convert your json. The results are below:

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
    public class Datum    {
        public int type { get; set; } 
        public string name { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Root    {
        public object groups { get; set; } 
        public List<Datum> data { get; set; } 
        public int total { get; set; } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need either continue parsing by properties and create new instance of `JsonModel` manually:

```
var result = new JsonModel
{
    data = new [] {parsedResponse["data"].Last.ToObject<JsonModel.Date>()},
    groups = parsedResponse["groups"].ToObject<object>(),
    total = parsedResponse["total"].Value<int>()
};
```

Or you can deserialize to it and reassign the `data` property:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModel>(response.content);
result.data = new[] {result.data.Last()};
```

Comment: Thanks. I have one question. If I want to store the objects data for only one of its values.. and not in an array.. Can I do it.. Sometime like this                                                           
  var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModel>(response.content);
result.data = new result.data.Last();

Comment: I am doing some json validation comparison and I am trying to extract the last data values and groups and total properties..

Comment: @KevinDavis965 I would say that no, cause `Last` returns an element from a collection, so your code will require `result.data` to be an collection and an element at a time, which is usually not very good.